# Firefox triggers elements hover without hovering over those elements

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

After last Firefox update to version 69.0, I have a navigation opens sub-menu on hover, this menu got trigger its hover state even if I didn't hover over it, this issue happens only on Firefox

here is a link to the video describing the issue
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AtEQeX5ub4v01XC8RXxDi9SDTABy?e=tZ0fmR

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You might want to reread both [ask] and [answer]

Answer (score -1):

The issue was happening because the sub-menu has property visibility: hidden, I changed it to display: none, and it worked as expected